# R function returns data when certain input is FALSE, returns nothing when TRUE

Tags: r

I've created a function to retrieve information from a data.table that meets a criteria. The function requires a TRUE or FALSE input to get only rows with a certain value, or all rows without that value.

In this reproducible example, I want to retrieve flowers with a given sepal length. Sometimes I only want virginica flowers, sometimes I want every other flower.

```
# Create a data.table from iris
iris_dt <- as.data.table(iris)

# Create function that lets you select sepal length and
# whether you want only virginica or anything but virginica 
select_virginica <- function (sep_l,virg){
  data_flowers <- iris_dt[which(Sepal.Length==sep_l)] 
  
  if (virg==TRUE){
    data_flowers[which (Species=="virginica")]}
  
  if (virg==FALSE){
    data_flowers[which (Species!="virginica")]}
}

# Check all non-virginica with sepal length = 5.8
select_virginica(5.8,virg=F)
# This correctly returns information on 4 flowers

# Check all virginica with sepal length = 5.8
select_virginica(5.8,virg=T)
# This incorrectly returns nothing. How do I fix this?
```

When it returns correctly (because I inputted FALSE), I can further select data from the results easily.

```
# I can work with the results in an interesting way, and easily select data from it
select_virginica(5.8,virg=F)[which (Petal.Length == 1.2)]
select_virginica(5.8,virg=F)[,3]
```

Some diagnostics and fix attempts:

It's not a problem in the dataset, because there are suitable rows with all three species

```
# There are flowers of Sepal.Length==5.8 in all three species
subset(iris_dt,Sepal.Length==5.8)
```

The function uses `which` after the dataset, but the issue is identical even if I use `subset` instead.

If I add `%>% print()` after `"virginica")]` I can get it to print, but then I can't use the function in that interesting way.

Why is this happening? How can I get the function to return my desired rows, and to be able to select rows in that interesting way? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use `return()` explicitly then your function will return the last evaluated line. The way you've implemented your function, you need to use `return()`. Like this:

```
select_virginica <- function (sep_l,virg){
  data_flowers <- iris_dt[which(Sepal.Length==sep_l)] 
  
  if (virg==TRUE){
    return(data_flowers[which (Species=="virginica")])
  }
  
  if (virg==FALSE){
    return(data_flowers[which (Species!="virginica")])
  }
}
```

Or you could rewrite it so that the last line is always the appropriate value to return:

```
select_virginica <- function (sep_l,virg){
  data_flowers <- iris_dt[which(Sepal.Length==sep_l)] 
  
  if (virg==TRUE){
    data_flowers <- data_flowers[which (Species=="virginica")]}
  
  if (virg==FALSE){
    data_flowers <- data_flowers[which (Species!="virginica")]}

  data_flowers
}
```

As a side-note, `==TRUE` and `==FALSE` aren't the best ways to check if a value is TRUE or FALSE. Stylistically, I'd prefer `if(virg)` and `if(!virg)`, but if you want to be more explicit use `isTRUE()` and `isFALSE()`, it will be more robust to `NA` values and different classes and such.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing two if's, use an if/else

```
select_virginica <- function (sep_l,virg){
  data_flowers <- iris_dt[which(Sepal.Length==sep_l)] 
  
  if (virg==TRUE) {
    data_flowers[which (Species=="virginica")]
  } else {
    data_flowers[which (Species!="virginica")]}
  }
}
```

If you don't have a `return()` statement in your function, R will return the last expression evaluated in your function body. If you do `if(virg==FALSE)` that's a stamement and since you didn't give an `else`, the `if` will return a NULL value implicitly. By using if/else, the function will return one of the two cases.